# sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.7 netmask 255.255.255.0 not permanent

Tags: linux-networking, ubuntu-12.04, static-ip, ifconfig

I have two PC's and a series of Juniper EX-2200 switches connected to form a network.None of the devices are connected to any external network.If I do an ifconfig on the first PC (monitor) I see that that PC only has an ethernet address.It does not have an IP address.I want to use an IP address to use applications such as scp.

So I do the following.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.7 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Now if I do an ifconfig the PC shows the IP address of 192.168.1.7 as expected.However it does n't seem to retains the IP address.It seems to lose the IP address after some time.I never rebooted the PC.It is likely that I am receiving ARP traffic on this PC.Can that cause the PC to lose the IP address.If yes,How can I cause the PC to retain the IP address

The route -n on the PC produces the following lines.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use  Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1000   0        0  eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0  eth0
```

It looks like the default gateway in this case is 0.0.0.0

Comment: Which distro your PC is running?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to keep it permanently, something like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.7
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Comment: can I give the gateway address (192.168.1.1) as dummy.Or do I need to have a machine with that IP in the network?

Comment: and afterwards do I need to restart the script or something?

Comment: 1. What is your current default gateway `route -n`? 2. Restart the network to make it take effect: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Comment: route -n outputs two lines with Destination Gateway Genmask values.Both the lines have Gateway (0.0.0.0)

Comment: just change the `gateway` line to `0.0.0.0`, basically it means "anything".